# Select the radio when you click on a textbox that's inside of a label

Tags: jquery, html, css

When a `textbox` inside of a label tag is clicked, I would like for the associated radio option to be selected as well. (Much like when the words in a label tag are clicked, it selects the associated radio option)

I've setup the problem below, is there a simple CSS solution? If not, a JS or JQuery solution will be okay as an alternative.

HTML Setup:

```
<input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="my-radio" >
<label for="radio-1"> Enter Value 1:
  <input type="text" > <!-- clicking this needs to select radio-1 -->
</label>

<input id="radio-2" type="radio" name="my-radio" >
<label for="radio-2"> Enter Value 2:
  <input type="text" > <!-- clicking this needs to select radio-2 -->
</label>
```

JS Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f8zpxmnk/1/

Edit: See picture for clarification

[image]

Edit 2: Here's a more in-depth JSFiddle of what I'm looking to do. I'm using custom icons instead of the radio buttons, not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Since you're saying there should only be 1 label per input, is there a better way to structure the HTML?

https://jsfiddle.net/y4pzawkm/1/

Comment: What if one doesn't enters any text? C'mon... you can do better at least at explaining some simple edge cases! :) And don't forget to show what you tried :)

Comment: This is just a simplified example to show the functionality of what I'm looking for-- clicking the textbox selects the radio. In my real-life application, the textbox is disabled, and doesn't get enabled until the radio is selected. But if the user tries to click the disabled textbox nothing happens. Not sure though how adding more variables to my question is going to help with the solution...

Comment: Exactly like you explained it here!! By narrowing your problem with more description (ok, without exaggerating) and by adding some code that as closely as possible reflects your problem - you can get much more accurate answers

Comment: I'm trying to avoid JS if possible. I was hoping there was a solution using CSS -- perhaps that would place the label above the textbox on the z-index so a click on the textbox, would register as click on the label.

Comment: Just, in your question you ask to select the checkbox **when a text is clicked**, but in your comments you say that **text inputs are disabled by default** - now everything makes less sense... Am I missing something here? I'm asking cause a disabled element cannot receive click event.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When you first mouse-click the textbox (i.e. give the textbox focus), I want that to select the radio. Much like when you click a regular label (that doesn't have a textbox inside), if you click that it selects the radio. NOTE: Whether the textbox is disabled or enabled, neither one when clicked will select the radio.

Comment: Sorry :) but I lost you totally now :D can you try to [edit] your question?

Comment: I mean, I see from your HTML markup what you're trying to do, but that's completely incorrect. A `label` element can reference only one action element, not two - so JS seems like a viable solution - but in such case there are several edge cases that would make any answer bad UI/UX - simply bad examples of doing the right thing. If you explain better your case and EACTLY what it does and how it should work, probably a better idea/solution would rise.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is **bad design** You should not have an unrelated input inside a `<label for>` element! Think about accessibility!

A `<label>` element can and **should reference only one formElement**. Either by wrapping it or by ID reference - using the `for` attribute.

Therefore remove the `for` attribute, change your HTML markup and use a bit of  jQuery:

**Instead:**

```js
$('[data-for]').on("click", function() { // on text input click...
  $($(this).data("for")).prop("checked", true); // get selector and make checked
});
```

```html
<label>
    <input id="radio-1" type="radio" value="1" name="my-radio" >
    Enter Value 1:
</label>
<input data-for="#radio-1" type="text" placeholder="click me" >

<br><br>

<label>
    <input id="radio-2" type="radio" value="2" name="my-radio" >
    Enter Value 2:
</label>
<input data-for="#radio-2" type="text" placeholder="click me" >



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I cannot even imagine after playing with the above what you're actually after. But hope this solution helps at least to improve your UI idea.

Comment: it always toggle for me even if there is text

Comment: @TemaniAfif the idea is silly anyways - but mine was to: 1) you click on an input and don't enter any text - on blur the radio will become unckecked. 2) if you enter some text - the radio will stay checked 3) what happens after messing around is simply bad design.

Comment: Hey thanks Roko, I should be able to take what you provided and apply that for my needs, thanks again.

Comment: @Wellspring you're welcome! Really hope the above helps somehow :\